# Remote Content - Blocking CSS Overrides

Tags: css

I am working on a system that will allow users to embed content into a web page that they have access to.

Conceptually the user would create a div with a specific id (let's call it "myId") on their page, and include a JavaScript file that I control which would basically inject markup into "myId".

The markup returned would include divs with inline styles to them.  I can't allow the users who are embedding this content into their page override the CSS styles.

I've read hundreds of articles and threads about CSS Specificity, !Important, etc.  It seems the only true way to block users from overriding your styles is to use iFrames.

Below are three articles a few co-workers and I have been bouncing around.
http://weblog.bocoup.com/3pjs-css-defense/
https://speakerdeck.com/antonkovalyov/achieving-harmony-with-third-party-javascript
http://weblog.bocoup.com/3pjs-css-delivery/

One of the concerns is that iOS will stop supporting iFrames, and honestly we've all been told for years not to use iFrames.  While it seems like the perfect and only solution it really does sound "hacky".

Does anyone have any insight into any other solutions?  I looked at how linkedIn embeds their "connect with linkedIn button" and they are simply wrapping every property value with an !important (which a) seem super hacky and b) doesn't account for undeclared properties and values).

Comment: Have you tried placing your stylesheet link after the point that their content and script is rendered. If the user styles are placed before yours and you use !Important, your styles should override theirs

Comment: The problem is they can include styles after my content has been loaded, so they always have the last laugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main concern with !important is that they can still override it with a later declaration using the !important keyword.

You are right about iFrames.

So you are not left with a lot of options:

- one option is to prepend your own CSS declarations with a custom non-generic package-like name so that the chances the user will override them will be very slim:

  .content h1

will become

```
.my-custom-css .content h1
```

- the other option is to modify their css markdown instead of yours. Prepend each of their declarations with a specific css class and use that class for their div container so it applies to all of its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however so far it looks like my only true option to block them from CSS overrides is to use iFrames.  Ugh.

Comment: Yep. Likewise with javascript as well.